# Angular2 app won't run with firebug up

Tags: javascript, angular

ReferenceError: webpackJsonpac__name_ is not defined
x2

The webpage loads up just fine, but if I pull up firebug and refresh I get the above error and the page won't load. Anyone seen this behavior before with their angular2 builds?

I'm using a pretty fresh build of this webpack starter: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a file webpack-dev-server.js that is missing a definition for webpackJsonpac__name.

In the src/index.html file just comment out the script tag (everything runs fine without it from what I can see)

```
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.isDevServer && htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.HMR !== true) { %>
  <!-- Webpack Dev Server reload -->
  <!--<script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>-->
<% } %>
```

Hope this helps someone! I'll make a comment on here if I notice any weird quirks from removing this (and will make a bug report)